# Emulator with API 15 and Android 4.0.3 shows in settings 4.0.4

Tags: android-emulator

I need to emulate Android device (Samsung Tab 2) with version 4.0.3, but after choosing it in Android Virtual Device Manager and running it I get info in settings that it is a 4.0.4 version.

I need to run my web app written in html5 to reproduce some bugs.

Any idea about it?

Comment: If you're going to reproduce a device-specific bug, better do it on the real device. Doing it on an emulator is very unlikely to give you a useful result. If you can't obtain the device, and your app is relatively lightweight (a web app as you say), you might be able to go to an electronics shop and try it on the devices they have on display.

Comment: You are right, but still I would like to run 4.0.3. I know that bug exists and I need to reproduce it to be able to debug it which I couldn't do in a shop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the emulator Android versions only correspond with specific versions from each API level. 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 are both in API level 15, so the emulator is only made available for Android 4.0.4. There is no Android 4.0.3 emulator; you'd have to find the system image for that or [build it yourself](http://source.android.com/source/building.html).

Comment: OK, thanks. I am doing now repo sync. Can you tell me maybe there is possibility to have at least the same browser version as it was in 4.0.3?

Comment: No, because the Samsung Galaxy Tab probably has its own browser (or at the very least one that was customized by Samsung). And you won't have the code for that browser because it's privately owned by Samsung. Modifications they made to certain parts may be open sourced due to the GPL, though.

Comment: So, basically, you cannot guarantee that you will get the same browser. You also don't know which exact revision of AOSP Samsung used to make their 4.0.3.